# Cordova Installation Issue

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

```
 npm ERR! Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
 npm ERR!     at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1381:32)
 npm ERR!     at SecurePair.emit (events.js:92:17)
 npm ERR!     at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:980:10)
```

How do I resolve this type pf CERT_UNTRUSTED issue with cordova?

I tried this command as well:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false

npm config set strict-ssl false

npm install -g cordova
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
npm ERR! <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/html4/strict.dtd">
npm ERR! <html>
npm ERR! <head>
npm ERR! <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859>
npm ERR! <title>Connect Error</title>
npm ERR! <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://registry.npmjs.org/%24%24%24%26%26%3f%24%24%24cmd=get_file&arg=block_style.css&sid=BEC8C289A9A5DE0FB7FCF45FF089A5978C175" type="text/css">
npm ERR! </head>
npm ERR! <body>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! <div id="pagecontainer">
npm ERR!         <img class="icon" src="https://registry.npmjs.org/%24%24%24%3f%26%3f%24%24%24?  cmd=get_file&arg=images/block.png&sid=40078573687B43FE5729956319CEF3479DB74"
npm ERR!         <h1>Could not connect to server</h1>
npm ERR!
npm ERR!         <div class="row">
npm ERR!                 <p class="label">Overview:</p>
npm ERR!                 <p class="item">Could not connect to registry.npmjs.
.</p>
npm ERR!         </div>
npm ERR!         <div class="row">
npm ERR!                 <p class="label">Details:</p>
npm ERR!                 <p class="item">Peer suddenly disconnected found</p>
npm ERR!         </div>
npm ERR!
npm ERR!         <div id="options">
npm ERR!                 <p class="label">Options:</p>
npm ERR!                 <form action=""><input type="button" class="button"click="history.back();" value="   Go Back   "></form><p class="item">Pressing button allows you to go to the previous page.</p>
npm ERR!                 <p class="last-item">You can try to reload the page
check if the URL is correct.</p>
npm ERR!         </div>
npm ERR!
npm ERR!         <div><img class="logo" title="Websense" src="https://registrpmjs.org/%24%24%24%26%3f%26%3f%24%24%24cmd=get_file&arg=images/wslogo_block_e.png&sid=CC7ECAEDE4907BCA9C2E449D9F12E1601D42E845"alt="WebsenseLogo">
npm ERR!                 <div style="clear: both; overflow: hidden; height:1p
```

> npm ERR!         
>       npm ERR! 
>       npm ERR!
>       npm ERR! 
>       npm ERR! 
>       npm ERR!     at Object.parse (native)
>       npm ERR!     at RegClient. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\n
>       node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:274:23)
>       npm ERR!     at Request._callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\n
>       _modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:246:65)
>       npm ERR!     at Request.self.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\n
>       node_modules\request\request.js:236:22)
>       npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       npm ERR!     at Request. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
>       de_modules\request\request.js:1142:14)
>       npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
>       npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_mod
>       s\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1096:12)
>       npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
>       npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:944:16
>       npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
>       npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
>       npm ERR!     http://github.com/npm/npm/issues

```
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\
```

ejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
    npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\salangar
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
    npm ERR! type unexpected_token
    npm ERR! not ok code 0

```
node -v
v0.10.35
```

Comment: I've foudn this : https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8894.
Seems like it has been patched in the new version, doesn't it ? It your npm client up to date ?

Comment: I have my node version - 0.12.4 and I still did not understand clearly, on "how to fix this issue"? using the github solution mentioned above?